# Example of D3 USA Map done in angular2

Tags: dictionary, d3.js, typescript, angular

I want to implement this D3 map of the united states using typescript in angular2  http://bl.ocks.org/NPashaP/a74faf20b492ad377312
Anyone know some good examples that can help me out? I couldn't find any good assistance for this anywhere. Thanks.

Comment: javascript is valid typescript, so the example you linked should do just fine. :)

Comment: do you need help setting up an angular 2 project to do the same?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a component for this and leverage the `ViewChild` decorator to reference the elements of the template (svg and tooltip) and configure them within the `ngAfterViewInit` hook method.

Here is a sample of use:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'us-map',
  template: `
    <div #tooltip></div>
    <svg #statesvg width="960" height="600"></svg>
  `
})
export class UsMapSvg {
  @ViewChild('tooltip')
  tooltipElt:ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('statesvg')
  statesvgElt:ElementRef;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
  function mouseOver(d){
        d3.select("#tooltip").transition().duration(200).style("opacity", .9);      

        d3.select("#tooltip").html(toolTip(d.n, data[d.id]))  
            .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")     
            .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");
    }

    function mouseOut(){
        d3.select("#tooltip")
          .transition()
          .duration(500).style("opacity", 0);      
    }

    let uStatePaths = (...)
    d3.select(this.statesvg.nativeElement).selectAll(".state")
        .data(uStatePaths).enter()
        .append("path")
        .attr("class","state")
        .attr("d",function(d){ return d.d;})
        .style("fill",function(d){ return data[d.id].color; })
        .on("mouseover", () => {
          d3.select(this.tooltip.nativeElement)
            .transition()
            .duration(200)
            .style("opacity", .9);      
          (...)
        })
        .on("mouseout", () => {
          (...)
        });
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, what elements are you trying to refer to when you write "elementRef"?

Comment: You're welcome! I reference elements with # (for example `<div #tooltip></div>`). The parameter in the `ViewChild` corresponds to what you have after the `#`. `ElementRef` is a "wrapper" around DOM elements...

Comment: one more question:
on these lines 
              d3.select("#tooltip").html(tooltip(d.n, data[d.id]))
             .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")
             .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");
it doesn't recognize tooltip or data. Should I use this.tooltipElt?
also what pages do pageX and pageY refer to?